# copy MySQL data from old database to new database but the new table with more columns

Tags: mysql, copy

I know I can copy data based on following command:
INSERT INTO NewDB.address_book SELECT * FROM OldDB.address_book

But if there are more columns in NewDB.address_book, what should I do? TIA.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to name the columns that you wish to insert the old data into and identically name the "old" columns in your SELECT query. The new columns in NewDB.address_book which are not referenced here will be filled with their default values.

```
INSERT INTO NewDB.address_book (column1, column2, column3)
SELECT
  old_column1,
  old_column2,
  old_column3
FROM
  OldDB.address_book
```